# QuerySet Error when replacing the User Detail View in django_rest_auth

Tags: django-views, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am trying to create a Custom User and Profile with `django_rest_auth` and have followed the docs in the FAQ about creating a User Serializer, but am confused about changing the User view.

Now, I've tried to replace the `UserDetailsView` in `django_rest_auth` with a custom one called `CustomUserDetailsView`, accessible using a similar URL as before for Users: `url(r'^user/$', views.CustomUserDetailsView.as_view(), name=...)`, which at the moment is an exact copy of `rest_auth.views.UserDetailsView`, but with `serializer_class` assigned to a custom UserDetailsSerializer, and am coming across an error when making a GET call:

```
AssertionError: 'CustomUserDetailsView' should either include a
`queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method.
```

The error message is quite clear as to what I should do, include a `queryset` attribute or override the `get_queryset()` method in my custom UserDetailsView view, but why was this not required in `rest_auth.views.UserDetailsView`?

Many thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the view implements `get_object` which has priority over `get_queryset`. That's why it works.

Also in DRA you can simply override `USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER` setting instead. Take a look at the docs for more details: http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

In you models.py:

Remove below line:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Instead have below lines:

```
# Default user model may get swapped out of the system and hence.
#from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```